# Invocable Methods: How to return a collection of records to flow

Tags: apex, invocable-method

This is my first time posting in StackExchange, and my first real attempt to put together some code.

I am attempting to query CampaignMembers from the data base after passing a CampaignID to the class from a Flow. Once the Apex executes I would like to return a collection of CampaignMembers to the Flow including Id,ContactId,CampaignId.

I understand a list of lists may be required to achieve my desired outcome, but I'm unable to hack it together.

I've copied my code below.

```
global with sharing class ReturnCampaignMembers {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<Results> GetStatus (List<Requests> requests)
       {
           ID v_camId = '7015A000001qWPcQAM';
           List<CampaignMember> rc_CM = [SELECT Id, ContactId, Contact.AccountId, CampaignId 
                 FROM CampaignMember WHERE Contact.Account.UpsellOpportunity__c='Yes' 
                 AND Contact.Account.Rating='High' AND CampaignId = : v_camId];

        Results curResult = new Results();

       List<Results> resultsList = new List<results>();          
        resultsList.add(curResult);
        return resultsList;
       }
        global class Results {
            @InvocableVariable
            global ID campaignmemberId;

            @InvocableVariable
            global ID campaignId;

            @InvocableVariable
            global ID contactId;

        }
        global class Requests {
            @InvocableVariable
            global String v_camId;  
        }     
}
```

Comment: You have to return list<list<Result>> from invocable to get a collection in flow.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? I understand the concept, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that when writing invokable action, you actually write code which is running on multiple batched flows. So the logic inside the should loop List requests and apply the logic to each Request. Each request comes from one flow, If many flows are started at the same time. And that in a single flow when building it you have access to only one Results record. In order to have a list of objects returned you have to use somewhat of a wrapper object result and to have list varuable in that result (wrapper) object. In your case:

```
global class Result {
                @InvocableVariable
                global List<CampaignMemberWrapper> campaignMembers;
            }

global class CampaignMemberWrapper {
          
            global ID campaignmemberId;

            global ID campaignId;

            global ID contactId;

        }
```

The begging of your method also needs work you should loop trough List requests and apply the logic for all requests. In the loop you assemble one "Result" object for each loop and put them in a list with results and then return that list.

I also suggest watching a few videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSqy1LWU9_o

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXcES3tkw9Y

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V47MarDONY0

Comment: This seems to work in apex, but in flow the members of CampaignMemberWrapper are not accessible from the flow.

Comment: You should keep in mind that when returned in a single flow there is only one campaign member wrapper. if you wish to return a list of records to every single flow then the structure of the result object must be a List of Lists. I believe if you watch the videos mentioned you will get the idea.

Comment: I understand that concept. I have the same structure as suggested in this answer (list of custom result objects, this object has a list of cutom payload object as a member), problem is fields of this payload objects show an error if used in flow (yet work in apex)

Comment: It is a bit shot in the dark, but I remember that sometimes the structure returned in the flow was a list with one object in it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return List> to get collection in flow. Please follow the link to understand more: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pOpyQAE